# changing the format of timestamp in python

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to change the timestamp from one format to another. I tried some approaches but i am not able to succeed.

This is my timestamp
**151005-12:07:34.917928**

I would like to change it to a format like this 
**2015-10-05 12:07:34:917928**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Show your code that you tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way using regular expressions:

```
import re
e = '(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})-(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.(\d+)'
s = '151005-12:07:34.917928'
print('20{}-{}-{} {}:{}'.format(*re.search(e, s).groups()))

2015-10-05 12:07:34:917928
```

Here's another using the `datetime` module:

```
import datetime
e = '%y%m%d-%H:%M:%S.%f'
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, e)
print(datetime.datetime.strftime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f'))

2015-10-05 12:07:34:917928
```

Comment: note: the `datetime` approach validates the values and therefore it should be used if the input data may be invalid.