# how to convert timestamp to date and change format

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timestamp

I have the following variable start_date:

```
start_date
Timestamp('2003-03-31 00:00:00')
```

I want it to become: 31-03-2003

so I want the minut hours seconds to be removed and also the format to change as %d%m%Y

Can anybody help?
Luigi

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969113/changing-the-format-of-timestamp-in-python This approach might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
start_date = start_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
```

Thanks

Luigi

Comment: side note: if you're using Python 3.7 or higher, you can use `datetime.fromisoformat()` instead of `strptime` to parse timestamp strings of that format [pretty efficiently.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468126/a-faster-strptime)